# Remove handle from vanity faucet

Tags: plumbing, sink, plumbing-fixture

first time on this forum. My vanity sink has been leaking when the water is turned on. I found a video explaining how to remove this type of handle' However when I removed the screw, the handle would not lift off. It feels like it is not meant to be removed, but that doesn’t seem right. Attached is a picture of the sink handle

[image]

Please let me know if you have any other ideas for how to remove the handle.

Edit 1.
The leak is coming out where the handle attaches to the body of the faucet. The connection is right under the hot/cold indicator.

Edit 2.

Thanks for the replies everyone. There was a lot of calcium buildup but I was able to get the handle off. It looks like the top of the cartridge is leaking. I went to a plumbing supply store and they said it has to be the exact one. I am not sure what I have exactly or how to check. Here is a picture:

https://imgur.io/a/NNW6e5N

I noticed there are some plastic scraps inside. Not sure where they came from or if it could be related to the issue. How would I go about finding a replacement? I am unable to see any info on it. Besides “chixin” which I think is the brand.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone. the handle was just really stuck on. after using some WD40, it was able to come off. after disassembling and reassembling, it stopped leaking.

Comment: Where is it leaking from?

Comment: Just updated with more info.

Comment: Once the set screw is out you should be able to pull the handle straight up. Might have a little calcium buildup making it stick. Try squirting a little penetrating oil up under the handle. Once it's off you'll get a better idea of the origin of the leak. You'll probably need a new cartridge. Turn off both the hot and cold shutoff valves under the sink before doing any repairs.

Comment: did you unscrew the handle @ruskes

Comment: there must be a set of numbers if not a name and numbers printed or stamped on the side of the cartridge.

Comment: Could just be a cheap Chinesium faucet, and might be easier to just replace the whole thing than just the cartridge.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but you can probably pop off that hot/cold button and find a set screw underneath.

Answer (score 1):

That hot and cold indicator usually hides a set screw. Most times it's an allen head screw.

Remove that set screw and the handle will come off and reveal the cartridge and the cartridge retainer.  Then you can get a better idea of what exactly is leaking.